# Help understanding the proof: A topological space that admits countable base is separable

Tags: general-topology

This proof can be founded on the John L. Kelley book's, and I can't understand it. But it also seems very elegant, and I am truly interested in to know it.

The proof is as follows:

Choose a point out of each member of the base, thus obtaining a countable set $A$. The complement of the closure of $A$ is an open set which, being disjoint from $A$, contains no non-void member of the base and is hence void.

There are several points that are not clear to me. First, I am taking for each element of the base an point out of it. I mean, let $\{B_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ the base. For each $i \in \mathbb{N},$ am I choosing $x_i$ out of $B_i$?

Ok, supposing that is this, why the complement of the closure of $A$ contains no non-void member of the base? And why this implies that it is void?

If someone could explain me the details I will be very grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\mathcal B$ is a countable base, and enumerate it: $\mathcal B = \{B_1,\cdots\}$. Now pick $x_i\in B_i$ for each $i=1,2,\ldots$ and form the set $A=\{x_1,\ldots\}$ which is by construction at most countable (there might be repetitions amongst the $x_i$). Now take an arbitrary open set $U$ in $X$. Since $\mathcal B$ is a base, there is some $j$ such that $B_j\subseteq U$, and then $x_j\in U$. Thus it follows that $A\cap U$ is nonempty. It follows that $A$ meets every open set in $X$, and this means $A$ is dense.

Comment: nice answer! I appreciate. Thank you!

Comment: Just clarifying the details in the Kelley book. Notice that it generalizes. The weight $w(X)$ is the least infinite cardinal $k$ such that $X$ has a base $B$ with $|B|\leq k$.  The density $d(X)$ is the least infinite  cardinal $k'$ such that  $X$ ha a dense subset $D$ with $|D|\leq k'$,  So $d(X)\leq w(X)$....... $d(X)$ and $w(X)$ are 2 of a family called topological cardinal functions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $A$ is built by choosing one element from each nonempty element of the countable basis as you correctly guess.

The idea is proving that $A$ is dense in the space $X$. Consider $\overline{A}$ and its complement $U$, which is open by definition of closure. Therefore $U$ is the union of elements in the basis. However, as soon as a nonempty element of the basis $B$ is contained in $U$, we have 
$$
U\cap A\supset B\cap A\ne \emptyset,
$$
by definition of $A$. This is a contradiction. Therefore $U$ is empty. Consequently, $\overline{A}=X$ and $A$ is dense. Since $A$ is finite or countable by construction, $X$ is separable.

Comment: Why $U\cap A \neq \emptyset$ is a contradiction?
Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: @user Because $U$ is contained in the complement of $A$ by construction.

Comment: oh, right! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let $B$ be a base for the space $X.$ Let $B^*=B$ \ $\{\phi\}.$ Any  open  $S\subset X$ is equal to $\cup F$ for some $F\subset B.$ In particular when $S\ne \phi$ there must exist $f\in B^*$ with  $f\subset S.$

Now if $g(b)$ for each $b\in B^*$ then  no $b\in B^*$ is a subset of $S=X$\ Cl $\{g(b):b\in B\}$ because $g(b)\in b$  \ $S$ for each $b\in B^*.$ So $S=\phi$ and $\{g(b): b\in B^*\}$ is dense in $X$.

Comment: nice proof! Thanks for the answer.